# Too many hits from GoogleBot

Tags: googlebot, web-crawlers, crawl-rate

The last week I have about 500.000 hits/day from googlebot in one of my websites. As a result, the server has serious issues to handle the rest of the requests.

**What I have done**

1. Verified that it is a googlebot

All the IPs are in the format of 66.249.64.xxx. I followed what Google suggests and verified that it is official.

```
host 66.249.64.155
155.64.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer crawl-66-249-64-155.googlebot.com

host crawl-66-249-64-155.googlebot.com
crawl-66-249-64-155.googlebot.com has address 66.249.64.155
```

2. Reduce the crawl rate in the Google Search Console

Changed the "Limit Google's maximum crawl rate" to

```
0.01 requests per second
100 seconds between requests
```

3. Add a block on robots.txt

```
User-agent: Googlebot 
Disallow: /
```

4. Add an .htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^googlebot
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com/
```

I also found a page in Google that shows the Crawl Stats for the last 90 days. As I can see, it doesn't have any recent activity. When the last was on February (again with a high number of hits)

[image]

My last finding is the pages that crawl are from the shop part with all the different filters in the parameters like categories, tags and sorting. I am clearly out of ideas and Google Search helped as much as it could.

5. Exclude parameters from the Search Console tool https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters

I did this today, so it might need a couple of days for Google to apply it. I excluded the parameters, `min_price`, `max_price`, `filter_size`, `filter_color`, `filter_brand`, `filter_type` and `orderby`.

This is an example of the URL that GoogleBot hits

`https://www.example.com/product-category/woman/?filter_size=36&query_type_size=or&min_price=0&max_price=30`

Comment: This is very unusual behavior for Googlebot.   Googlebot is normally a very well behaved bot that is very careful not to put too much load on the the sites that it crawls.

Comment: What is your site, and how many pages are on your site?

Comment: Warning: your `Disallow: /` rule for Googlebot will remove most of your site from Google search within a couple weeks.

Comment: The crawl stats graph from Google search engine console may take a few days to update.    GSEC  often doesn't have the must up-to-date information in it.

Comment: I know about the robots.txt that will have a negative impact in the SEO, but I had to take an action until there is a more proper solution. The website in an eshop with about 250 products and 25 categories. Plus some tags. All the crawled urls are from the /shop page where it tries with all the possible parameters of sorting and categories.

Comment: What are some example URLs with the parameters for sorting and categories?   There should be a solution for blocking just those if we know the pattern.

Comment: This is very similar to somebody else that is currently having almost the same problem: [How to limit Google crawling certain URL patterns?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128655/how-to-limit-google-crawling-certain-url-patterns)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Updated with another step I tried and also added a url example

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think it's probably not Googlebot, it's quite easy to spoof the User Agent string, and with a bit more effort to report a false IP address.

Regardless, you're basically experiencing a Denial of Service attack so a service designed to prevent that (query 'edge server' on the search engine of your choice), or anything else that lightens the load on Apache, would probably help.

I almost always use Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Apache for a variety of reasons but cache and efficiency are a big part of it.

There is a way to set a `noindex` HTTP header in Apache but if it's ignoring `robots.txt` then I doubt that would help.

Comment: The steps outlined in the question mean that it isn't just user-agent spoofing.   The bot is using an IP address owned by Google.   See [Verifying Googlebot - Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en) where they talk about using this method to know if hits are actually from Googlebot or from a spoofed user agent.  I upvoted this answer because the rest of the content is good.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I agree it does appear to be from Google but sometimes when I look through my access logs, and check an I.P. address, I find it's completely non-existent. Because most people would never want to block GoogleBot, if I wanted to harass someone and bog down their server, I might fake a GoogleBot UserAgent string and use a tool like http://hexinject.sourceforge.net/ to also spoof a Google I.P. address...but I realize that is probably a stretch (and Google does have hiccups now and again) but that was my logic.